# Vectors convolution and independence between components

Tags: correlation, independence, multivariate-normal-distribution

I'm interested in correlation and dependence between the components of the convolution of two vectors taken from a zero-mean multivariate normal. Marginals are independent, each one with same variance.

Let's start from the simplest case: suppose we have two vectors from a bivariate normal distribution: 
$X,Y \sim N\big(
(\begin{smallmatrix}
0 \\
0 
\end{smallmatrix})
, 
(\begin{smallmatrix}
\sigma^2 && 0 \\
0 && \sigma^2
\end{smallmatrix}) \big)$. We write $X = \left[x_1 \quad x_2 \right]^T$, and $Y = \left[y_1 \quad y_2 \right]^T$. Now define a new vector $Z$ in this way:

$ Z =
\left[\begin{matrix} 
z_1 = x_1 \cdot y_2 + x_2 \cdot y_1 \\
z_2 = x_1 \cdot y_1 + x_2 \cdot y_2 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$

More generally, with a larger $n$ dimension, this can be stated as:

$ Z =
\left[\begin{matrix} 
z_1 = & x_1 \cdot y_n + x_2 \cdot y_{n-1} & + \ldots + & x_n*y_1 \\
z_2 = & x_1 \cdot y_1 + x_2 \cdot y_n & + \ldots + & x_n*y_{n-1} \\
\vdots & & & \\
z_n = & x_1 \cdot y_{n-1} + x_2 \cdot y_{n-2} & + \ldots + & x_n*y_n \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$

As you can see, every $z_i$ is the sum of products between distinct couples of independent marginal variables, among any equation (e.g. you see $x_1 \cdot y_2$ in $z_1$ and not in $z_2$).

Under which condition $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ may be assumed to be mutually uncorrelated or independent?